# Проверка винчестера в ubuntu

Tags: проверка, ubuntu

Комп стал выключаться сам, пишет panic  и т.д. Думаю это накрывается винчестер, какие есть хорошие проги на ubuntu для проверки жесткого диска ?

Comment: версия ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1):

badblocks и smartmontools помогут решить проблемы с hdd